# Question about finite sums and integer recursions.

Tags: number-theory, summation, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $g(n)$ be a given strictly increasing integer function such that $0<g(n)<n$ for all $n$.
Also the sequence $ |g(n) - n|$ is unbounded as $n$ grows.

Let $f(1)=1$ and further 
$$
f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{g(n)}f(k)
$$

Now I know that if $g(n)$ is close to $\dfrac{n}{2}$ then $f(n) = O(\exp(\ln(n)^{2-o(1)}))$

See : http://oeis.org/A000123 and http://oeis.org/A018819

The question is how to find the asymptotic to $f(n)$ (like above) when given $g(n)$ ?

For instance I assume if $g(n)$ is close to $\dfrac{n}{a}$ for $0.4<a<0.6$ then also $f(n) = O(\exp(\ln(n)^{2-o(1)}))$ but that could be completely wrong.

What happens for $g(n)$ being close to $ A n^B $ or $n - A n^B$ ?

Or $g(n)$ close to $\ln(n)$ or $n - \ln(n)$ ? Can we still express such slow/fast growth ?

How about $g(n)$ being the prime counting function ?

Of course I know some trivial brute boundaries such as $f(n) < 2^n$ or $f(n)<fib(n)$ , but Im looking for better boundaries.

I hope this question is not too general.

Comment: We can try to estimate $f(n)$ by the following asymptotic heuristics. Let $N$ be a large number and $F$ and $G$ be sufficiently smooth functions on $[0,1]$ such that $G(0)=F(0)=0$, $F\left(\tfrac nN\right)=f(n) $ and $G\left(\tfrac nN\right)=\tfrac{g(n)}N$ for each $1\le n\le N$. Then for $x=\tfrac nN$ we have 
$$F(x)=F\left(\frac nN\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{g(n)} F\left(\frac kN\right)\approx N\int_0^{G(x)} F(t)dt$$
Differentiating we obtain $$F’(x)\approx NG’(x) F(G(x)).$$